# Are there any obstacles of using windows Bluetooth API from the driver?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, driver

Google/MSDN say nothing about that but I'm still suspicious: it is possible to build a driver, it is possible to build a [C++] Bluetooth application, but what if I use BT API from driver? Anyone with related experience?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out by myself:  BLE API which is available in Win 10 is part of the new UWP API. We found no way to use UWP from driver - so this is not possible.